# Preventing overlapping on changing size

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent a block from overlapping the rest of the content when the user changes the size of the content (Ctrl + Scroll normally).

Here is the website which I am developing: http://irchound.tk/ and I am facing problems on the homepage. If I zoom out then the tables overlap the content on the left.

**I am using margins to place the Ranking, News Feed, IRC Stats & IRC table in the right and the overall page has margins on left and right to keep the content in the center**

Here is the type of code I'm using:

```
<div id="page">
<content>
<table id="news">
<content>
</table>
<other tables with id "news">
</div>
```

and then rest of the content. Here is the website CSS: http://irchound.tk/CSS.css

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The overall structure of your site is poorly implemented, you should never be using `<br>` tags to introduce whitespace, make use of CSS for this.

Currently, the hierarchy of your elements is what is causing elements to overlap, judging by your layout I think you'd want something more like this:

```css
#mainWrapper {
  width: 600px;
  height: 100%;
}

#navigation {
  height: 50px;
  background: #000;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#navigation ul {
  padding-top: 15px;
} 

#navigation li {
  display: inline;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 0px;
}

#pageBody {
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  height: 300px;
}

#newsFeed {
  width: 29%;
  float:right;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 300px;
}

.newsSection {
  background: blue;
  height: 97px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.newsSection p {
  margin: 0px;
}

footer {
  color: white;
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mainWrapper">
   <header>
      <nav id="navigation">
         <ul>
           <li>Some Link</li> 
           <li>Some Link</li> 
           <li>Some Link</li> 
         </ul>
      </nav>
   </header>
  
   <section id="pageBody">
     <p>Some content about the page here</p>
   </section>
  
   <aside id="newsFeed">
      <div class="newsSection">
        <p>Some news info</p>
      </div>
     
     <div class="newsSection">
       <p>Some news info</p>
     </div>
     
     <div class="newsSection">
       <p>Some news info</p>
     </div>
   </aside>
      
   <footer>
     <p>Here is some footer</p>
   </footer>
</div>
```

Now you'll notice that if you view the snippet I provided as a full page, it wont change as you zoom in or out - I have not provided any responsive design, but this should be a start for you.

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. I will work on the website asap. Still learning stuff. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey, you're welcome - we all start somewhere :). If this solved your problem consider up voting and marking this as your answer